# How to setup this GUI with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I got a GUI to make and I've tried so many ways, but I can't seem to build it correctly, I always get the layouts wrong and my application gets all messed up. I just want some help on how to build something close to the GUI in the image, except the image part, that isn't necessary. Doesn't need to be exactly like it, I just need some ideas of what layouts to use and how. Thanks
[image: 1]]

Comment: Take a look at the `GridBagLayout` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with all problems, start by breaking it down into manageable chunks.

Associate the various UI elements together into groups of "functionality" and separate them into separate components - this way you can focus on the individual layout requirements for each section

[image: Overall layout]

From this, I would then focus on breaking down each group into individual components and focus on there core functionality

[image: Options]

So this is pretty basic, I'd use a `GridBagLayout` because it would allow me to anchor the components to the top position of the container. You could also use the `VerticalLayout` from SwingX

[image: Lists]

So, there are a number of possibilities, but, because it would be simple to do, I'd use a `GridBagLayout`, as it would allow me to provide more space for the two lists

[image: Profiles]

A little more complicated, but still, `GridBagLayout`, as it allows more control over providing space to individual components

[image: Playbar]

And, `GridBagLayout` for all the reasons highlighted above.

## Finally...

Bringing it all together...

I'd probably start by placing the green, blue and yellow sections into a separate container (using, surprise, a `GridBaglayout`, as it allows for components to expand cells) and then combine it with the purple section onto a container using a `BorderLayout`

I would recommend that you take the time to look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and try somethings and see what does and doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir! Will try to do something and I can give you a return tomorrow. BTW, really good explanation and breakdown, I actually didn't think of that layout divison.